# Similar font to Montserrat that is native to Microsoft 365

Tags: microsoft-office

Working with a small business that has recently migrated from Google Workspace to Microsoft 365. Their current font choice is Montserrat but this is a Google Font.

Can anyone recommend a native Microsoft 365 font that is most similar to Montserrat?

The desired outcome is to be able to create documents within Microsoft 365 Office apps for the web (eg Word https://www.office.com/launch/word ) with their font of choice that is similar to Montserrat (for consistency with previously created documents).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr for taking the time to respond. Yes, that is how the PCs are setup now. As far as I am aware, fonts cannot be installed/uploaded to Microsoft 365 that allow for documents to be created in Microsoft 365 web apps with non-native Microsoft 365 fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use locally installed fonts in the Microsoft Office web apps. It's not obvious though, requires a little trick!

1. Download the Montserrat font family from the [Google fonts site](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?query=montserrat), open the zip, and go into the folder called "Static". Here you will find all the TTF files.
2. Open any of the Montserrat font TTF files in the font viewer, then take a note of its exact name. Write it down. And hit Install. Repeat for all the TTF files you want to install.

Here's an example showing Montserrat-Regular.ttf - the font name is just "Montserrat"

[image]

3. Open the Microsoft Word web app in your browser, and type some text, and highlight it.
4. In the font drop down you will not find the font listed, but you can type in the exact name of the font that you wrote down earlier.

Here's an example of Montserrat (installed locally) being used in the Word web app.
[image]
Click to see larger

The only real downside to this is that you need to know the exact names of the fonts so you can type them in manually. You also need to type the exact name with no spelling mistakes, or it won't work. Note that anyone else viewing the file will also need to install the fonts locally on their computer. Such is life though!!

Comment: Awesome - that is great to know! Thank you! 

I'm a bit surprised that I'm getting some feedback that this is "a bit too tricky for some users". 

Would you happen to know a Microsoft 365 web app font that is most similar to Montserrat?

Comment: @Nic - unfortunately not, I don't use it often enough. Maybe just look through those that are available in the drop down.  There will be several sans serif fonts though.

Answer (score 1):

You want a geometric sans-serif, one with proportions based on a circle. Century Gothic is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Corbel` looks rather similar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116857)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116856)